# Using identification in a label in prometheus. Best practices for labeling

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I would like to know if it's possible in prometheus to use a label to set an identification (paymentId for example). I suppose it is not the point of this tool because we would generate a thousands of metrics and the store is very limited.
My point of this is to identify in prometheus with an alert when a payment is not successful. So I can generate alert with the payment ID. Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really possible in Prometheus, it is designed so you can alert on the fact that some level of payments are failing but not the specific payments that are the problem.

I'd suggest using a logs-based monitoring system such as ELK for this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.